# How to change the bootloader during system installation?

Tags: grub-efi

My laptop doesn't want to work with GRUB, but it works fine with rEFInd and manjaro. But now I want to install Ubuntu and I don't know how to make it immediately install rEFInd. Maybe someone knows how to do this? (sorry for my english it's all google translate)

Answer (score 2):

During the Ubuntu installation, there is not much you can do. You have to make all the choices before the installation or if you made a mistake, you have to wait and reinstall again with the configuration that you like :)

Comment: It's just that during installation, an error pops up and the system does not start in any way, believe me, I tried a lot of things, GRUB does not start anyway

Comment: @OлесьПідкаура Can you send the eror? So I can say what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to know where the option to select Device for boot loader installation is at when installing Ubuntu.

During installation, there will be the following page titled "Installation type" with option like "Erase disk and install Ubuntu", etc:
[image: options of installation type during ubuntu installation]

Select "Something else" in it and click "Install Now".
In next page, there will be a drop-down menu at bottom that reads "Device for boot loader installation".
[image: dropdown to select device to install boot loader]

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: No, it doesn't work, and I know that, he will put grub and I need him to put rEFInd